# MySQL how do I update multiple columns from the same row in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to update one table that looks like the following.

```
ItemID  FID1    FID2    FID3    FName1  FName2  FName3  
100084  2545    2536    2535
```

Using data from another table. The other table looks like:

```
FID    FName
2545   Name 1
2534   Name 3
2536   Name 2
```

I want the updated table to look like:

```
ItemID  FID1    FID2    FID3    FName1  FName2  FName3  
100084  2545    2536    2535    Name 1  Name 2  Name 3
```

What is a clean way to do this in a single query?

Comment: You delete the first table. You alter the second table and add `ItemID` column. Then you pour gasoline and acid on the file that contained the first table so you never make such an atrocity again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't ask why you want to store your data in a non-normalized form ;-) - But this should work:

```
update one_table t
left join other_table t1 on t1.FID = t.FID1
left join other_table t2 on t2.FID = t.FID2
left join other_table t3 on t3.FID = t.FID3
set t.FName1 = t1.Fname,
    t.FName2 = t2.Fname,
    t.FName3 = t3.Fname
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm inheriting these tables so that's the excuse I'm going with.

Comment: After seeing the horrendous performance of this query and the feedback from you and @n-b I was able to get additional time so I could change the tables. Woot!